# Строки изменяются в js

Tags: javascript

Строки в js неизменяемы. Только вот почему у меня она изменяется в функции?

```js
const ucFirst = (str) => {
   str = 'Лена'
   return str
}


console.log(ucFirst('Вася'));
```

Comment: Ты путаешь строки и значения в переменных

Comment: @АлексейШиманский можно поподробнее?

Comment: Строки как тип данных неизменяемы, просто переменная начинает ссылаться на другую область в памяти - на другую строку.

Comment: @salco202020 В твоём примере нет работы со строкой. Ты просто поменял  значение в переменной. Вместо этих значений могли быть любые другие.

Comment: @Leonid const ucFirst = (str) => {
   return str.toUpperCase()
}

console.log(ucFirst('Вася')); А, в этом случае? Тут ведь работаю со входящим аргументом, строкой, но она тоже меняется. Чтот не могу понять))

Comment: Попробуй `let s = 'test'; s[1] = 'o'; console.log(s);`. В языках с изменяемыми строками такая замена символов возможна, в языках с неизменяемыми - соотв., нет. Твой пример не меняет строку, а создает новую.

Comment: Не меняется. Функция `str.toUpperCase()` вернула *новую* строку.

Comment: @yar85 так не меняется, да. Но, если тоже самое сделать в функции, значение меняется. Значит в функцию попадает не строка, а ее копия?

Comment: @AlexeyTen понял спасибо!

Comment: Попадает сама строка, не копия. Но ты меняешь значение переменной, а не строку. Строки в JS - примитивы, они передаются значением, а не по ссылке. То есть: получил значение в параметр, затем заменил это значение на другое (переданное аргументом значение не изменилось, оно именно заменилось другим значением).

Comment: @yar85 Благодарю за ответ!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не изменили строку, вы просто присвоили переменной другое значение, присвоили новую строку вместо прежней.

Возможные примеры неизменяемости строк:

```js
const str = 'Лена';
str[0] = 'Г';
console.log(str); // Всё ещё 'Лена', а не 'Гена'.
str.length = 2;
console.log(str); // Всё ещё 'Лена', а не 'Ле'.
const newStr = str.toUpperCase();
console.log(str); // Всё ещё 'Лена', а не 'ЛЕНА'.
console.log(newStr); // 'ЛЕНА', но это другая строка в другой переменной.
```

В строгом режиме (`'use strict';`) эти попытки вызывают исключения (ошибки).